# QTcpSocket - try to send bunch of requests

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to send 2 request one by one at same time. My code is following (this is example code):

```
QTcpSocket client;
...
client->write(block);
client->write(block);
```

Problem is following. Server receives only first request. There is no second request. I sniffed using wireshark and see that there is no second request in tcp packets.

What must i do to send many requests via QTcpSocket one by one?

**UPD**: I inserted `qDebug() << this->bytesAvailable() << "bytes";` to server in readyRead()  and `qDebug() << this->bytesToWrite();` after each `client->write(block);` in client. Also, I added this to client:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(bytesWritten(qint64)));

void Connection::bytesWritten(qint64 count)
{
    qDebug() << count << "bytes written";
}
```

I send ORDER_STATUS_GET_LIST constant in first request and ORDER_GET_LIST in second. I added data output in server. I received first command.

There is output listing:

Client:

```
Sending ORDER_STATUS_GET_LIST 
11 bytes to write 
Sending ORDER_GET_LIST 
68 bytes to write
68 bytes written
```

Server:

```
68 bytes 
ORDER_STATUS_GET_LIST received
```

Comment: Could you check the output out QTcpSocket::write? It should return how many bytes have been written.

Comment: Can you show the code for the slot connected to the `readyRead()` signal on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you need to `flush()` the socket IF you don't return to the event loop between multiple writes.

The proper solution would be to buffer your blocks into, e.g., a `QByteArray` and send the buffer at once.

```
QTcpSocket client;
QByteArray buffer;
...
buffer << block;
buffer << block;
client->write(buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found solution myself. I think that somebody needs this too.

Solution is simple:

```
QTcpSocket client;
...
client->write(block); 
client->flush();
client->write(block);
client->flush();
```

We need to flush qt socket buffer to net before fill it with another data.